# Pandas dataframe diff except some rows?

Tags: pandas

```
df  
   end_date    dt_eps   
0   20200930    0.9625
1   20200630    0.5200
2   20200331    0.2130
3   20191231    1.2700
4   20190930    -0.1017
5   20190630    -0.1058
6   20190331    0.0021
7   20181231    0.0100
```

Note: the value of `end_date` must be the last day of each year quarter and the sequence is sorted by near and the type is string.

**Goal**

create `q_dt_eps` column: calculate the diff of `dt_eps` between the nearest day but it is the same as `dt_eps` when the quarter is Q1. For example, the `q_dt_eps` for `20200930` is 0.4425(0.9625-0.5200) while `20200331` is 1.2700.

**Try**

```
df['q_dt_eps']=df['dt_eps'].diff(periods=-1)
```

But it could not return the same value of dt_eps when the quarter is Q1.

Comment: "Does not work" is pretty vague. What do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just convert the date to `datetime`, extract the quarter of the date, and then create your new column using `np.where`, keeping the original value when quarter is equal to 1, otherwise using the shifted value.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'end_date':['20200930', '20200630', '20200331', 
    '20191231', '20190930', '20190630', '20190331', '20181231'], 
    'dt_eps':[0.9625, 0.52, 0.213, 1.27, -.1017, -.1058, .0021, .01]})

df['end_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['end_date'], format='%Y%m%d')

df['qtr'] = df['end_date'].dt.quarter

df['q_dt_eps'] = np.where(df['qtr']==1, df['dt_eps'], df['dt_eps'].diff(-1))

df
```

```
    end_date  dt_eps  qtr  q_dt_eps
0 2020-09-30  0.9625    3    0.4425
1 2020-06-30  0.5200    2    0.3070
2 2020-03-31  0.2130    1    0.2130
3 2019-12-31  1.2700    4    1.3717
4 2019-09-30 -0.1017    3    0.0041
5 2019-06-30 -0.1058    2   -0.1079
6 2019-03-31  0.0021    1    0.0021
7 2018-12-31  0.0100    4       NaN
```